# Derive daily mean from high frequency measures

Tags: r, time-series, average, openair

I have 15-min observations of air temperature `Temp` data that I would like to derive a daily mean for. I have been trying to use the `openair` package with the `timeAverage` function to get to this answer because it allows the user to set a minimum threshold for the amount of missing data that is allowed before it will derive a daily mean. However I keep getting the same error message associated with not being able to find the variable `date`.

Here is an example of my dataframe

```
> head(dat)
              Date Temp
1: 2001-01-01 0:00   NA     
2: 2001-01-01 0:15 -1.4
3: 2001-01-01 0:30 -1.1
4: 2001-01-01 0:45 -1.1
5: 2001-01-01 1:00 -0.9
6: 2001-01-01 1:15 -0.5
```

here is the code I have been using

```
dailyAVG <- timeAverage(mydata = dat,
                        avg.time = "day",
                        data.thresh = 75,
                        statistic = "mean",
                        start.date = "2001-01-01 0:00")
```

which produces this error message

```
Can't find the variable(s) date 
Error in checkPrep(mydata, vars, type = "default", remove.calm = FALSE,  :
```

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(dat, 15))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky way to get around the error message. What I did was rename the `Date` column in MS Excel to `date`. I then, also in MS Excel, reformatted the `date` column to be in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm. After making these corrections I read the .csv file into `R` and made the following adjustments.

This first correction, get the `date` format into one that `openair` likes

```
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date, tz = "", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

After fixing the `date` format, I ran into another issue related to my temperature `Temp` measurements. For some reason, R was seeing the values as class character, when they should be numeric. This was fixed with

```
dat$Temp <- as.numeric(dat$Temp)
```

After making these corrections, the function `timeAverage` worked using the following code

```
dailyAVG <- timeAverage(mydata = dat,
                        avg.time = "day",
                        data.thresh = 75)
```

```
> dailyAVG
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  date                 Temp
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2001-01-01 00:00:00  3.01
2 2001-01-02 00:00:00  1.85
```